# using printenv in script sh in recovery TWRP return error execv failed : Exec format error

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, scripts

for example just try this script

```
#!/sbin/sh

printenv | grep sdcard >> /tmp/tong.txt
```

in recovery.log i've

```
run_program: execv failed: Exec format error
run_program: child exited with status 1
```

I think it's about printenv but i don't understand what is wrong.
Using printenv in a terminal emulator works but not in my script sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

printenv doesn't work but using env works well

so i changed my script like this

```
env > /tmp/tong.txt
```

it works as expected